# Regex: Exclude first line

Tags: regex

I've gone over solutions to similar answers on SE but they haven't worked for me.

Assume the following input:

> @@A small note
>
> Thanks
>
> [Here](http://foo.com) or [there][1]
>
> #### A very nice thing
>
> [1]: http://home.com

I want to exclude the first line. So my final output needs to be the text above, but starting with the line that says "Thanks" (not a blank line).

How can this be done?

Comment: Well, `re.sub(r"(?m)^@@.*[\r\n]*", "", s)` (if you need it for Python)?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes I'm starting to suspect that maybe the app I'm using (Workflow) doesn't support this kind of regex filtering since what your suggestion is returning is exactly the line I want to *omit*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not for Python. It's actually a workflow action in the Workflow app for iOS

Comment: And what will you do if the line is in between other lines?  Regex engines cannot match discontinuous texts. You will need to either replace or concatenate matches/groups.

Comment: We can safely assume it's the always the first line that we want to omit.

Comment: Try [`(?ms)(?!\A)^.*`](https://regex101.com/r/GCtTuR/1) (maybe you will need to double the backslashes). If you need to check for the first `@@`, try *capturing* what you need - [`^(?:@@.*[\r\n]*)?(?s)(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/GCtTuR/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that last one worked! I assume it has nothing to do with the @@ I mentioned though. Originally the goal was to have the @@ identify the title of a text, while the rest is the content. But I guess this will have to do. Thank you.

Comment: So, shall I post and explain `^(?:@@.*[\r\n]*)?(?s)(.*)`?

Comment: What worked was actually the second one.

Comment: The second one like `(?ms)(?!\A)^.*`? :) Sorry, I am sleepy now, and I posted 3 regexps, but left just 2. I also keep losing the Internet connection.

Comment: The one that worked: (?ms)(?!\A)^\S.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider matching the start of a line other than the first line in the string, that starts with a non-whitespace char, and then match everything up to the string end.

You may use

```
(?ms)(?!\A)^\S.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCtTuR/3).

**Details**:

- `(?ms)` - MULTILINE (`m`) modifier making `^` match the start of a *line*
  and the DOTALL modifier (`s`) that makes a `.` match any chars including line breaks
- `(?!\A)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the current location is the start of the string (`\A` always matches the start of a string regardless of the presence of the MULTILINE modifier)
- `^` - start of a line
- `\S` - a non-whitespace char (if there may be leading whitespace before the first non-whitespace char, add `[^\S\r\n]*` before `\S`)
- `.*`  - any 0+ chars up to the string end.

Comment: As I understand from the comments simply omitting @@ in the middle of a multi-paragraph text isn't possible, so this solution will have to do. Appreciate your help!